# glm rotation not working properly

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, rotation, glm-math

I am trying to rotate a cube around the X and the Y axis. I don't know why it doesn't work for this two and it only works around the Z axis. By not working I mean the cube is also moving and it's not rotating in place.

The relevant code I use is:

```
void rotateZ(float angle) {
        _modelMatrix = glm::rotate(_modelMatrix, -angle, glm::vec3(0,0,1));
    }
    void rotateY(float angle) {
        _modelMatrix = glm::rotate(_modelMatrix, -angle, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
    }
    void rotateX(float angle) {
        _modelMatrix = glm::rotate(_modelMatrix, -angle, glm::vec3(1,0,0));
    }
    void translate_to_origin() {
        _modelMatrix = glm::translate(_modelMatrix, glm::vec3(-(_x + _n/2), -(_y +  _n/2), -(_z + _n/2)));
    }   
    void translate_to_position() {
        _modelMatrix = glm::translate(_modelMatrix, glm::vec3(_x + _n/2, _y + _n/2, _z + _n/2));
    }
    void translate (float x, float y, float z) {
        _modelMatrix = glm::translate(_modelMatrix, glm::vec3(x, y, z));
    }

    void create(float x, float y, float z, float n) {


                std::vector<MyVertexFormat>verts;
                std::vector<glm::uvec3>indx;


                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y,  z,  1,0,0));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y,  z,  1,0,0));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y,  z - n,  0,1,0));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y,  z - n,  0,0,1));

                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y + n,  z,  1,0,0));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y + n,  z,  1,0,0));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y + n,  z - n,  1,0,1));
                verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y - n,  z - n,  1,1,1));


        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(0,1,2));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(2,3,0));

        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(4,5,6));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(6,7,4));


        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(0,1,4));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(4,5,1));


        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(1,2,5));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(5,6,2));


        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(0,3,4));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(4,7,3));


        indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(2,3,7));
                indx.push_back(glm::uvec3(7,6,2));


        //vao
                glGenVertexArrays(1, &mesh_vao);
                glBindVertexArray(mesh_vao);

                //vbo
                glGenBuffers(1, &mesh_vbo);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh_vbo);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(MyVertexFormat) * verts.size(), &verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

                //ibo
                glGenBuffers(1, &mesh_ibo);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh_ibo);
                glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * indx.size() * 3, &indx[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

                int pipe = glGetAttribLocation(_glProgramShader, "in_position");
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(pipe);
                glVertexAttribPointer(pipe, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MyVertexFormat), (void*)0);

                pipe = glGetAttribLocation(_glProgramShader, "in_color");
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(pipe);
                glVertexAttribPointer(pipe, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MyVertexFormat), (void*)sizeof(glm::vec3));
                mesh_num_indices = indx.size() * 3;
    }
```

To rotate the cube I use:

```
cube->translate_to_position();
cube->rotateY(angle);
cube->translate_to_origin();
```

Comment: I haven't studied the whole thing, but the operators used in `translate_to_origin()` look inconsistent. Why are you using `-` for x, but `+` for y and z?

Comment: Sorry.. that was just an editing error. I edited the post

Comment: There's some strangeness in the vertex coordinates as well. Partly it's ` + n` , partly ` - n` . For example for the y coordinate, it uses all of `y`, `y + n` and `y - n`. I don't think you'll get a cube from that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! I wasn't constructing the cub correctly. The right way was

```
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y,  z,  1,0,0));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y,  z,  1,0,0));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y,  z + n,  0,1,0));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y,  z + n,  0,0,1));

            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y + n,  z,  1,0,0));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y + n,  z,  1,0,0));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x + n,   y + n,  z + n,  1,0,1));
            verts.push_back(MyVertexFormat(x,   y + n,  z + n,  1,1,1));
```